# Run a script on multiple files using numbers in their names

Tags: file, shell, sh

I have a script that I want to run on multiple files, the way I run it now is this way:

```
for input in /home/arashsa/duo-bokmaal/Bokmaal/*.txt ; do
    name=$(basename "$input")
    /corpora/bokm/tools/The-Oslo-Bergen-Tagger/./tag-lbk.sh "$input" > "/home/arashsa/duo-bokmaal-obt/$name"
done
```

The textfiles (on first line) that I run this on are named in this fashion:

```
DUO_BM_{number}.txt
```

where {number} is a number between 0 and 40000. There are not 40000 files though, some numbers are missing, so it might go 1, 2, 5, 10, 13, etc. How would I go about if I want to run the script on files from 0 to 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do this:

```
for ((i=0; i <= 100; i++)); do
  name=DUO_BM_${i}.txt
  input=/home/arashsa/duo-bokmaal/Bokmaal/$name
  if test -e "$input"; then
    /corpora/bokm/tools/The-Oslo-Bergen-Tagger/./tag-lbk.sh "$input" > "/home/arashsa/duo-bokmaal-obt/$name"
  fi
done
```

Comment: @ArashSaidi there were some issues with the arithmetic for loop. It should now work correctly in `bash` (but not `sh`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your word for it, as I am now running the modified version I have posted below, which worked for me. If anybody tried to run a function based on the method above and get an error, please comment here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                 

for i in `seq 0 5`; do
  name=DUO_BM_${i}.txt
  input=/home/arashsa/duo-bokmaal/Bokmaal/$name
  if test -e $input; then
    /corpora/bokm/tools/The-Oslo-Bergen-Tagger/./tag-lbk.sh "$input" > "/home/arashsa/duo-bokmaal-obt/$name"
  fi
done
```